# What ship classes are shown in "Relativity"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, object-identification

The first 21 seconds of the *Star Trek: Voyager* episode "Relativity" show the Utopia Planitia ship yards for the first time in Star Trek. During these 21 seconds I counted at least 15 ships which can be seen in drydock. Which ships have identifying characteristics which let us pinpoint their classes, and what are they (where the ship is seen, identifying characteristic and class)?

In particular, a few people have noticed a Galaxy-class ship at some point during this sequence. (In fact, there's a rumour that it's actually the Enterprise-D being refitted in between TNG and Generations.) Others noticed an Ambassador-class ship. But I can't exactly pinpoint where they are in the sequence and how we know they are of those classes.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Many of the ships are too small to be distinctly seen. But several classes can be definitively identified. In the opening sequence, I can see:

- The primary hull of a [**Galaxy**-class](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Galaxy_class) vessel under construction.
  [image: Incomplete galaxy saucer]
- Another Galaxy-class vessel, this one fully constructed. I can't definitively rule out the possibility that this is the *Enterprise-D*, but I can't find any direct evidence supporting this idea either.

[image: galaxy class in spacedock]

- At least two [**Akira**-class](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Akira_class) vessels. I say at least two because while one is clearly leaving spacedock, the other two may be the same ship from different angles.

[image: akira class in spacedock]

[image: akira class leaving spacedock]

[image: another akira class in spacedock]

- An [**Excelsior**-class](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Excelsior_class) vessel. At first I thought this was an Ambassador class, but the dark shapes on the primary hull aft of the bridge clearly match the Excelsior.

[image: excelsior class in spacedock]

- Two of what Memory Alpha identifies as [**Saber**-class](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Saber_class) vessels. The second one is rather dubious in my opinion.

[image: saber class in spacedock]

[image: very small and blurry image of what is allegedly a saber class]

- The [**Intrepid**-class](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Intrepid_class) *USS Voyager*.

[image: uss voyager in spacedock]

- Many unidentified ships that don't resemble any recognizable classes. I can't find anymore information on these.

Memory Alpha claims that a [**Steamrunner**-class](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Steamrunner_class) vessel is present in this episode, but no image is provided and I cannot find one in the footage.

Comment: According to Memory Alpha, there is also at least one [Steamrunner class ship](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Steamrunner_class) to be seen.